# Determine top t values with few calls to order(), a given procedure to order k values, Java take 2

Tags: java, programming-challenge, sorting

My 2nd take of the problem in [Determine top *t* values with few calls to `order()`, a given procedure to order *k* values](/q/287745/93149):

> Given an array and a procedure to order \$k\$ elements,
> return an array containing the top \$t\$ elements
> *using no other comparisons of elements*.

The challenge:
For \$n\$ elements, use fewer calls to the order procedure than \$(n+t)/(k-t)\$
(See the basic procedure implemented as `topByOrderK(E[] many, int t, int k, OrderK<E> orderK)` below.)

Take 2 has grown a bit long, I tried to arrange it to read well top down.
The non-basic procedure works for \$k\le t\$, too.
Some peculiarities (such as preferring String[] over Integer[] or "the `!equals` loop") are owed to observing/debugging with Eclipse Neon&JDT 3.12.3.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.IntFunction;

/** Determine top t values given a procedure to order k values<br/>
 * - and <em>no</em> other way to compare values. */
// the following - assumes it impossible to tell where in an ordered
//                 array a value p known to be included is
// - does not currently try to be smart about n-t much smaller than n/2
public class TopByOrderK<E> {
    // The basic algorithm:
    /** Returns the top <code>t</code> values.<br/>
     * Uses about <code>length/(k-t)</code> calls to <code>order</code>.<br/>
     * Optimal for <code>t=1</code> as well as
     *  <code>t&lt;k</code> and small <code>length</code>.
     * @return a new E[] containing the top t values among the first <code>length</code>
     *                    values from <code>many</code>.
     * @param many at least <em><code>k</code></em> values.
     *        May be mutated.
     * @param length >= k how many values to process. */
    /* Repeat: order k values, advance by k-t until no k elements left. 
    // Order last k values & return an E[] of the last t ones.       */
    public static <E> E[] 
    topByOrderK(E[] many, int t, int k, OrderK<E> orderK) {
        if (k <= t)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("number of values"
                + " that can be ordered by a single call needs to"
                + " exceed the number of top values to determine"
                + " for the basic procedure to be applicable.");
        for (int start = many.length - k ; 0 < start ; start -= k - t)
            orderK.apply(many, start, k);
        orderK.apply(many, 0, k);
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(many, 0, t);
    }
    
    final int t, k;
    // "semi-final": not set in constructor as potentially not needed
    E[] candidates[];  // top t candidates by possible rank
    int offsets[];     // of next element of candidates to fill
    
    /** Returns the top <code>t</code> values - in any order.<br/>
     * <code>many</code> might get mutated.<br/>
     * <strong>Not</strong> thread safe/synchronised. */
    /*/ Keeping values by possible rank allows 1 < k <= t
    //  only place many may get mutated is handleSpecialCases deciding
    //  to use the basic procedure */
    public E[] topByOrderK(E[] many) {
        E[] scratch = handleSpecialCases(many);
        if (scratch.length == t)  // already handled as a special case
            return scratch;

        instantiateBuffers(t, many, scratch);

        scratch[0] = many[0];  // scratch[0] contains the champion

        for (int done = 1, k_1 = k - 1, limit = many.length - k_1 ; ; ) {
            System.arraycopy(many, done, scratch, 1, k_1);
            orderK(scratch);
            keep(scratch, 0, 1, k);  // leaves champion in scratch[0]
            if (limit < (done += k_1))
                return wrapUp(many, scratch, done);
        }
    }


    /** @param many the values to pick top <code>t</code> from.
     *  @return a new <code>E[]</code>, containing the top <code>t</code>
     *             values if <code>.length == t</code>,<br/> 
     *             else long enough for wrap-up as regular handling is due          
     */
    E[] handleSpecialCases(E[] many) {
        final int n = many.length;
        if (n < t)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("number of values supplied"
                + " may not be less than number of result values required.");
        if (n == t)
            return many.clone(); // result _not_ ordered
        if (t < k && k <= n      // basic procedure has a chance to work 
            && (t == 1 || n < k * k))  // and uses fewest calls to order
            return topByOrderK(many, t, k, order);
        E[]scratch = Arrays.copyOf(many, Math.max(t, k) + k);
        if (k < n)
            return scratch;      // regular case
        assert(n < k);
        return handleLessThanK(scratch, n);
    }

    /** If less than k elements, use value no greater than tth to pad */
    E[] handleLessThanK(E[] scratch, final int n) {
        assert k <= scratch.length;
        E fill;
        if (1 < t) {  // find value no greater than tth ...
            E[] toOrder = Arrays.copyOf(scratch, k);
            Arrays.fill(toOrder, n, k, scratch[0]);
            orderK(toOrder);  // ... at small end
            fill = toOrder[k-1];
        } else
            fill = scratch[0];
        Arrays.fill(scratch, n, k, fill);
        orderK(scratch);
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(scratch, 0, t);
    }

    /** Supports iteration of candidates known not to be #1.<br/>
     *  Can be interleaved with the relegation of values to lower ranks.<br/>
     *  Provides <code>rank()</code> of last element dished out. */
    class FurtherRunning implements Iterator<E> {
        int rank = 1;
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            while (offsets[rank] <= 0)
                if (offsets.length <= ++rank)
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public E next() {
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();
            E fr = candidates[rank][--offsets[rank]];
                      if (debug) candidates[rank][offsets[rank]] = null;
            return fr;
        }
        /** by and large, rank last next() came from */
        int rank() { return rank; }
    }

    private void
    instantiateBuffers(int t, E[] many, E[] scratch) {
        candidates = (E[][]) Array.newInstance(many.getClass(), t);
        candidates[0] = scratch;
        for (int r = 0 ; ++r < t ; )
            candidates[r] = Arrays.copyOfRange(scratch, 0, k);
        offsets = new int[t];
    }
    /** Order <code>candidates[rank]</code> and distribute these 
     *  <code>k</code> values to this and <code>k_1</code>
     *  "lower priority" <code>candidates</code> arrays. */
    // filling up a lower priority buffer results in a recursive call
    void keep(E values[], int rank, int known, int unordered) {
        for (int d = known ; d < unordered && ++rank < t; d++) {
            candidates[rank][offsets[rank]] = values[d];
            if (k <= ++offsets[rank]) {
                orderK(candidates[rank]);
                offsets[rank] = 1;
                keep(candidates[rank], rank, 1, k);
            }
        }                                 if (debug) pad(values, known);
    }

    /***/
    E[] wrapUp(final E[] many, E[] scratch, int done) {
        int filled = 1;  // in scratch
        int known;      {// number of known tops
        int left = many.length - done;
        if (0 < left) {  // append what's left of many
            System.arraycopy(many, done, scratch, 1, left);
            filled += left;
            known = 0;  // more than one top1 candidate
        } else
            known = 1;  // top1 known to be in scratch[0]
                                      } if (debug) pad(scratch, filled);
        for (FurtherRunning chasers = new FurtherRunning() ;
             known < t && chasers.hasNext() ; ) {
            scratch[filled++] = chasers.next();
            if (known + k <= filled) {
                orderK(scratch, known);
                int unordered = known + k;
                if (t <= (known = Math.max(known + 1, chasers.rank()))
                    || !chasers.hasNext())
                    return Arrays.copyOfRange(scratch, 0, t);
                keep(scratch, known, known + 1, unordered);
                filled = known + 1;
            }
        }
        if (filled < k)
            return handleLessThanK(scratch, filled);
        orderK(scratch, filled - k);
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(scratch, 0, t);
    }

    
    private final OrderK<E> order;
    public TopByOrderK(int top, int k) { this(top, k, null); }
    public TopByOrderK(int top, int k, OrderK<E> order) {
        if (top < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "number of top values required shall be at least 1.");
        if (k < 2)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("number of values that"
                + " can be ordered by a single call must exceed 1.");
        t = top;
        this.k = k;
        this.order = null == order ? new OrderK<E>() {} : order;
    }

    /** <code>apply(values, first, count)</code>
     *  orders <code>count</code> values in <code>E[] values</code>
     *  from <code>first</code> non-descendingly. */
    public interface OrderK<E> {
        /** <code>apply(values, first, count)</code>
         *  orders <code>count</code> values in <code>E [] values</code>
         *  from <code>first</code> non-descendingly. */
        public default void apply(E[] values, int offset, int k) {
            Arrays.sort(values, offset, offset + k);
        }
        public default void apply(E[] values, int k) { apply(values, 0, k); }
    }

    // monitoring
    int calls;
    void orderK(E[] values, int offset) {
        calls += 1;
        order.apply(values, offset, k);
    }
    void orderK(E[] values) { orderK(values, 0); }  // convenience

    // debug support
    static final Integer[] NO_INTEGERS = {};
    static final String[]  NO_STRINGS = {};
    static final boolean debug = true;
    static void pad(Object[] toPad, int fromOffset) {
        Arrays.fill(toPad, fromOffset, toPad.length, null);
    }

    static final char[]
        CONSONANTS = "bcdfghjklmnprstvwxz".toCharArray(),
        VOWELS = "aeiuoy".toCharArray(),
        CATEGORIES[] = { CONSONANTS, VOWELS };
    static final IntFunction<String> fromInt = new IntFunction<String>() {
            public String apply(int n) {
                if (n < 0)
                    return "";
                StringBuilder blurb = new StringBuilder();
                while (true)
                    for (char [] category: CATEGORIES) {
                        blurb.append(category[n % category.length]);
                        if (0 == (n /= category.length))
                            return blurb.toString();
                    }
            }
        };
    static <T> Set<T> toSet(T[]a) {
        return java.util.stream.Stream.of(a)
            .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toCollection(
                                               java.util.HashSet::new));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long seed = args.length <=0 ? System.nanoTime()
                                    : Long.valueOf(args[0]);
        System.out.println("seed: " + seed);
        java.util.Random randy = new java.util.Random(seed);

        for (int k = 2 ; k < 9 ; k++) {
            System.out.print(System.lineSeparator() + k + ": ");
            int tops[] = new int[5+k];
            tops[0] = 1;
            tops[1] = 2;
            for (int i = 2, t = k - 1 ; t <= k+k+1 ; t++, i++)
                tops[i] = t;
            String[] topT = {""};
            for (int t: tops) {
                TopByOrderK<String> topper = new TopByOrderK<>(t, k, null);
                for (int d = 0 ; d < 2 ; d++) {
                    int n_k_1 = 9999 / k / k;  // ToDo: small n
                    n_k_1 = n_k_1 * k;
                    Object[] more = randy.ints(n_k_1 + d, 1, n_k_1*4)
                        .mapToObj(fromInt).toArray();
                    String[] many = Arrays.copyOf(more, more.length,
                                                  NO_STRINGS.getClass()),
                        ordered = many.clone();
                    Arrays.sort(ordered);
                    String[] ok = Arrays.copyOfRange(ordered, 0, t);

                    topT = topper.topByOrderK(many.clone());
                    while (!Arrays.equals(topT, ok)) {
                        Arrays.sort(topT);
                        if (Arrays.equals(topT, ok))
                            break;
                        topT = topper.topByOrderK(many.clone());
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(topT));
        }   
    }
}
```

The one procedure exceeding 24 lines is `wrapUp()`.

Should `candidates`&`offsets`&`FurtherRunning` be a class ‹Keep› (‹Kept›?) in its own right?

Comment: (I found that running `d` from 0 to 2 in tests (`main()`) deserves a comment :-/)